# Access same BLOC object across different routes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am using [bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) library in flutter code. I need to access some BlocA on WidgetA and WidgetB. WidgetA and WidgetB are two different routes. Should I pass the instance of BlocA in constructor of WidgetB while pushing the WidgetB on top of WidgetA. I don't want to keep the BlocA as global as this will be basically used on just two pages. So, just wanted confirm if it would be an anti-pattern if I pass the instance of bloc in constructor.

Comment: You may check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528092/how-to-use-same-bloc-in-multiple-widgets/61530041#61530041

Comment: Thanks a ton @FederickJonathan, this really helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use same bloc in multiple widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528092/how-to-use-same-bloc-in-multiple-widgets)

Answer (score 1):

you can provide your bloc above your `MaterialApp`